# Solve for $x^2 + 7x +1 = 3n(x^2 + x +1), n \in \Bbb{Z}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

Solve for $x$ and $n$ in the equation
$$ \dfrac{x^2 + 7x +1}{ x^2 + x +1}= 3n,\qquad n \in \Bbb{Z}.$$
The original problem was a trigonometric equation but solved it till I got stuck here. I am a  high school student who is self studying and preparing for college entrance exam. Original problem was a trigonometric equation which came from 'cengage exam crack'.

[After Mark's and Jyrki's hints in the comments, I got the answer and posted it below.]
Original problem:
[image]

Comment: Is the value of $n$ known, or also for you to figure out?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen one have to find the all the possible value of n.

Comment: Have you tried clearing fractions and using the quadratic formula? You need the bit under the square root to be positive. @JyrkiLahtonen's  comment gives you the possible values of $n$

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I can convert numerator into whole square to find its range.  Hmm I looks like I don't got the tools you are talking about.  Will be great if you can give me source where I can get those tools.

Comment: @MarkBennet thank you. I got the answer. I also posted in below.

Comment: While I have nominated this question for reopening, I would personally like to seem more context included in the question. Specifically, you say that the problem started life as a trigonometric equation.  Editing this original trigonometric equation into the question would help pin down questions of domain (i.e. what values of $x$ and $n$ actually make sense, given that they have to be fed to some trig function).  A more complete reference to "engage exam crack" (whatever that is) would also be helpful.

Comment: @XanderHenderson what do you mean by 'more complete reference'?

Comment: @swarnim A reference is meant to give the reader enough information to find the source for themselves.  Right now, I have no idea what "cengage exam crack" is, nor where to find it.  If "cengage exam crack" is a book, a reference includes *at least* the entire title of the book and the name(s) of the author(s).  It is also helpful to include a year of publication, an edition number, and a publisher.  If "cengage exam crack" can be found on the internet, a link to the digital resource can provide a complete reference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1) Convert the problem into quadratic 
$ x^2(1-3n) + x(7-3n) + 1-3n = 0 $

2) set discriminant greater than equal to $0$

3) find the range of $n $

4) find the possible values of n which are $(0,1,-1)$

5) plug them back in to find values of $x$

Comment: That's a nice way of combining the steps. Well done!

Answer (score 2):

$3n
=\dfrac{x^2 + 7x +1}{ x^2 + x +1}
$
so
$3nx^2+3nx+3n
=x^2+7x+1
$
so
$(3n-1)x^2+(3n-7)x+3n-1
=0
$
or

$\begin{array}\\
x
&=\dfrac{-3n+7\pm \sqrt{(3n-7)^2-4(3n-1)^2}}{2(3n-1)}\\
&=\dfrac{-3n+7\pm \sqrt{(3n-7-2(3n-1))(3n-7+2(3n-1))}}{2(3n-1)}\\
&=\dfrac{-3n+7\pm \sqrt{(-3n-5)(9n-9)}}{2(3n-1)}\\
&=\dfrac{-3n+7\pm 3\sqrt{(-3n-5)(n-1)}}{2(3n-1)}\\
\end{array}
$

If nothing is specified about $x$,
this is as far as we can go.

If $x$ has to be real,
then
$(3n+5)(n-1) \le 0$
so that
$-\dfrac53 \le n \le 1$.
Since $n$  is an integer,
$n = -1, 0, 1$.

If $x$ is supposed to be rational,
then
$(3n-7)^2-4(3n-1)^2
=m^2
$.
From the preceding result,
$n=1
\implies
m^2
=4^2-4(2)^2
=0
$,
$n=0
\implies
m^2
=7^2-4(1)^2
=45
$,
$n=-1
\implies
m^2
=10^2-4(-4)^2
=36
$.

Therefore the only rational solutions
with integer $n$ are
$n=1, 0, -1$
for which
$n=1
\implies x
=\dfrac{-3n+7\pm 3\sqrt{(-3n-5)(n-1)}}{2(3n-1)}
=\dfrac{4}{4}
=1
$,
$n=0
\implies x
=\dfrac{-3n+7\pm 3\sqrt{(-3n-5)(n-1)}}{2(3n-1)}
=\dfrac{7\pm 3\sqrt{5}}{-2}
$,
and
$n=-1
\implies x
=\dfrac{-3n+7\pm 3\sqrt{(-3n-5)(n-1)}}{2(3n-1)}
=\dfrac{-10\pm 4}{-8}
=\dfrac{-14, -6}{-8}
=\dfrac74, \dfrac52
$.

Comment: Why did you exclude n= 0, if it is because it doesn't provide a rational solution , then question doesn't say anything about X to be rational or irrational but only real.

Comment: You are right. Added that case and upvoted your comment. Thanks,

Comment: The question doesn't actually say anything about $x$ being real, so why is everyone making that assumption?